# Meaning of the return of np.shape()

Tags: python, numpy, physics, shapes

I have a program in numpy utf8, which allows me to calculate the coordinates of a parabolic shot from the ground. I need to create a function which returns the coordinates (#1), create the different arrays of values to work with (#2), and finally use the function to generate the different coordinates for each pack of values

```
#1
def coordenadas(v,a,t,g=9.81):
    rad=deg2rad(a)
    x=v*cos(a)*t
    y=v*sin(a)*t-(1./2.)*g*(t**2)
    xy=array([x,y]).T
    return xy
#2
v=arange(50,100,10) #m/s
adegree=arange(45,90,5) #degrees
a=deg2rad(adegree) #rads
t=linspace(0,10,50) #segundos
#3
v.shape=(5,1,1)
a.shape=(1,9,1)
t.shape=(1,1,50)
#5
XY=coordenadas(v,a,t,g=9.81)
print shape(XY)
print XY
#4
```

My question is that shape(XY) returns

```
(50L, 9L, 5L, 2L)
```

And XY (only a bit, is too long)

```
[[[[   0.            0.        ]
   [   0.            0.        ]
   [   0.            0.        ]
   [   0.            0.        ]
   [   0.            0.        ]]
```

And more boxes of this shape

What this really means(big boxes, boxes, small boxes, rows, columns) ???

Comment: It seems, you are using numpy, so it's a good idea to keep the namespace, that other people see, that f.e. you are using numpy's deg2rad function. I advise you to read the basics about numpy arrays and their representation as well as their methods.

Answer (score 2):

`(50L, 9L, 5L, 2L)` means a `4D` array.

You can visualize as a `50x9` matrix and each cell of this matrix contains a `5x2` matrix

Comment: 50x9 matrix whereas each number is another matrix 5x2?? Thanks

Comment: Can I make it to a (5,9,50,2) array with shape, no?

Comment: I think it sees better like that

Comment: For changing the shape you can use `shape` or `reshape`

Comment: Ok, ive got it I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays are basically matrices, where each box [] represents the start of a new dimension. As an easy example the matrix

```
11
23
```

could be written in numpy as:

```
a = numpy.array([[1,1],[2,3]])
```

which then would be printed as

```
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

As this is a two-dimensional matrix, the outer "box" marks the edges of the matrix, whereas the inner boxes are the rows of the matrix with the `,` separating the entries. Calling `a.shape` without an argument gives the shape of the 2x2 matrix:

```
(2, 2)
```

Calling the `shape` method with argument reshapes the matrix given to the shape defined in the argument. But to further help you with the code:

## 1

Your function definition seems to be totally fine, except I don't see a reason, why you export x and y in an array, rather than just returning two different values.

## 2

The initialization of your arrays seem to be fine as well.

## 3

There is totally no reason to reshape the arrays you just created, just leave them as they are.

## 4

You have to call the function separately with each set of values to create the coordinates. Do that by using an itteration over the arrays you just created.

Comment: The reason of the without-reasonement things is that they were exercises